# DC/OS ssh connection refused on port 22 - preflight

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, dcos

Hi I am trying to setup DC/OS in Debian 8 Jessie, I got working ssh connection with the ssh key, I am able to login without password to all masters and agents (they are running CentOS 7). Strange thing is it's not working when running --preflight, it will say connection refused for all nodes.

`TASK:
/usr/bin/ssh -oConnectTimeout=10 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oBatchMode=yes -oPasswordAuthentication=no -p22 -i genconf/ssh_key -tt root@192.168.122.131 sudo rm -rf /opt/dcos_install_tmp
     STDERR:
          ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.131 port 22: Connection refused
     STDOUT:`

If I try to run this command in terminal, it works just fine. So it does not work only when running it via `bash dcos_generate_config.sh --prefligh`. Any idea what could be wrong please?

Comment: 1. That command could be running as a different user within preflight. 2. That ssh key might not exist yet at that point. 3. What version of DCOS is this?

Comment: It was latest version 1.9. It will be probably different user, but which one? Ssh key is for sure created already.

Answer (score 0):

In bash `--` denotes the end of command-line options, so what you need to probably do is:

```
bash dcos_generate_config.sh -- --prefligh
```

Comment: Nope, command option is working fine, it's running preflight, but it's failing on SSH connection.